# Are there slicers available in Superset?

Tags: date, apache-superset, slicers, defined

I am finding it extremely hard to find a slicer where user can define a custom date range to filter records. Power BI has this option. Has anyone come across similar issue? Is there a way to overcome?

I tried filter options, but cannot accept user defined date range

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.